# Replace SWIFT dictionary into JSON object

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I'm trying to remove an element from a dictionary in a JSON object in SwiftyJSON. I've tried converting the element into a dictionary, removing the element and replacing back as follows:

```
    var testJSON = JSON(["Item1":["1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"],"Item2":"Value2","Item3":"Value3","Item4":"Value4"])

    // convert to dictionary
    var jsonDict: [String:JSON] = testJSON["Item1"].dictionaryValue

    // remove element
    jsonDict.removeValueForKey("1")

    // replace into original
    testJSON["Item1"].dictionary = jsonDict
```

But I get this error

Error:  cannot assign [String:JSON] to a value of type [String:JSON]?

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign an optional to a non-optional.

```
.jsonvalue
```

returns an optional. Unwrap it first making sure it didn't return `nil` then assign it to the dictionary.

Comment: thanks I'm fairly new to swift. Did you mean to type .jsonvalue?